# Test if a file is loaded

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

Is there a way in phpUnit to test if for example a certain css file is loaded?

In other words, i want to check if a css file is loaded (if possible). I want to make sure the HMTL output has a style tag with a certain css file.

Comment: Your question is kinda vague because you can already use `$this->assertTrue($condition, $message='')` to test for something.  Are you talking about testing the CSS file handle?  Are you talking about if all the data in the CSS file was properly loaded?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Tnx. I added more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as
Foe example the page source will display the css file as

```
<style src="mycss.css" type="text/css"></style>
```

Then following statement will check that the element present or not

```
$this->assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("//style[@src='mycss.css']"));
```

Comment: Hi is not working Fatal error: Call to undefined method IndexControllerTest::isElementPresent() in
 K:\stage5\tests\application\controllers\IndexControllerTest.php on line 44